# How to find pandas dataframe rows satisfing a particular combinaison of values stored in a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table :

```
print(table) =
 
Index   Values   Scores   a   b   c
  1       90      99      1   0   0
  2      120      10      0   0   2
  3      280       8      1   2   0
  4       90      99      1   0   0
  5      120      10      1   0   0
  6      280       8      1   5   3
```

I have generated all a,b,c present combinations by deleting all duplicated values which result in
another table called combinations:

```
print(combinations) = 

a    b    c
1    0    0
0    0    2
1    2    0
1    5    3
```

What I would like to do is finding all rows of Table that are matching the first row of my Combination table in order to have this kind of output:

```
Index   Values   Scores   a   b   c
  1       90      99      1   0   0
  4       90      99      1   0   0
  5      120      10      1   0   0
```

I'm trying to use a function like `Table[Table.columns[9:len(Table)]] == combinations.iloc[1,:]`
But it's not working well. I can't use a classical  `a==x & b==y & c==z` because the input table will sometimes have more columns that should match values such as a b c and d..
Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, `iloc` slices by range index, i.e. from `0` to `len(data)-1`. And also, you need to check all the columns after comparison:

```
mask = (table[combinations.columns] == combinations.iloc[0]).all(1)
table[mask]
```

Output:

```
   Index  Values  Scores  a  b  c
0      1      90      99  1  0  0
3      4      90      99  1  0  0
4      5     120      10  1  0  0
```

Comment: Aahhh perfect that work exactly as expected, thanks a lot for that!